# Error loading data from a C# database application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, windows

I have created a C# database application, the database file is of type *.mdf* . The app works fine on my PC and in other PCs that have MS SQL Server already installed. In other machines that do not have SQL server installed, the installation process shows me an unhandled exception, after that, the app opens but no data are loaded .

The exception says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.).

This is the full exception in detail:

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot
>   find the file specified    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   ...
>
> ... at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>   ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:2,State:0,Class:20*

The app can run successfully but no data from database are loaded. 
Do I have to install SQL server express in all machines,so the app can load its required data, or just some components of SQL server are enough. Other PCs have Windows update disabled.

For more information here are application files:

- Data177k.mdf.deploy
- Data177k_log.ldf.deploy
- deatach.application
- deatach.exe.config.deploy
- deatach.exe.deploy
- deatach.exe.manifest
- setup.exe

What can I do in order that the app to load its database even in PCs that dont have SQL server express installed on.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server have you created the database in?
You normally need to install SQL Server on a PC for it to be able to attach and use an .MDF file.

Comment: SQL Server 2014 express @Culme

Comment: Your application can run succesfully while every single database request fails? I think you have some major issues with your error handling... In any case, the error message seems to be perfectly clear: "Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed." Why would you expect this to work *without* an SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read up on SQL Server LocalDB, which allows you to publish the necessary plumbing for using an .MDF file on a client computer, without installing SQL Server/Express on it.

[MSDN SQL 2014 Download and information page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx)